# Visual Studio MVC HTML Web Address

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I can make an address like

`www.mysite.com/person`

But how can I make it so that it's like

`www.mysite.com/person/john-bishop`

I guess I need both ID and name, in case there are multiple john bishops?

This is what I got so far

```
public ActionResult Person(int id, string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to pass the ID of the person, and have it add the associated persons name to the address (as in the address for this page - `stackoverflow.com/questions/28377973/visual-studio-mvc-html-web-address`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add an Id or unique identifier at the end.

```
www.mysite.com/person/john-bishop-1
www.mysite.com/person/john-bishop-2
```

and the RouteConfig

```
   routes.MapRoute("Person", "Person/{name}-{id}", new { controller = "Person", action = "Person" });
```